# copying dataframes values using a condition

Tags: r, dataframe, copy

i have two dataframes:

the first: `> vg<-data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5), value=c(5,0,1,0,5))`

```
> vg
  id value
1  1     5
2  2     0
3  3     1
4  4     5
5  5     1
```

the second:

```
> vg1<-data.frame(id=c(5,4,2,3,1), value=c(1,2,3,4,2))
> vg1
  id value
1  5     1
2  4     2
3  2     3
4  3     4
5  1     2
```

as output, i want to get this dataframe:

```
> vgf
  id value
1  5     1
2  4     2
3  2     3
4  3     1
5  1     2
```

the idea here, i want to get the `vgf$id` with the same order of `vg1$id`. and for `vgf$value`.  i start with "1" as value. 
my problem here, it's how can i do: `vgf[1]$id=5` and i give it as value 1, and i will try to find :

```
if(vg[i]$id=5){
vv<-vg[i]$value
}
```

and for all ids in `vg` for which its value is `vv` , I will store them on vgf giving them **1** as value for here `vgf$value` for the second id if it is not treated with the above I give it **2** as the value and repeat the process previous. I treat dataframe a thousand lines.

i will that problem is clear. thanks

Comment: It is not clear how you got the expected output

Comment: it's my question, for this example i do it manually. but i work with a dataframes of 1000 rows. so i am asking for help.

Comment: I understand that it is your question, but honestly, I didn't understand how you got the expected output.  If it was clear, I am sure somebody might have answered it very early.

Comment: The `if(vg[i]$id=5` should be `if(vg[i]$id==5` (i.e. change `=` to `==`).

Comment: @steveb, i don't how to get the output, here i do it manually to explain the problem. any help please

Comment: @arkun, the **vgf** outuput got `vgf$id<-vg1$id`. but  for the **vgf$value** i want to start by **1**. So for the first **vgf$id** i give it **vgf$value<-"1"** as value. but in the **vg** this **id** has another value, so what i want to do, it's when i will store the other ids in vgf that have the same value as this id, i will give them the same value which is **1**.

Comment: @arkun, for the second row of **vgf**: **vgf$id** is 4. as value i will give it **2**.and this id has as value in **vg** : 5. i will find all the **ids** in **vg** with this value **5**, and when i will store them in **vgf** i give them **2** as value. it's clear??

Answer (score 0):

vgf is vg2, so i initialize the vg2 as below:

```
vg2<-data.frame(id=vg1$id, value=c(-1))
```

and this code give the result.

```
az<-numeric()
d<-numeric()
m<-1
    for(i in 1:nrow(vg1)){   

    if(vg2$value[i] == -1)
    {
    bool<-0
    for(j in 1:nrow(vg))
    {
        if(vg1$id[i] == vg$id[j])
        {
            x<-vg$value[j]
            for (z in 1:nrow(vg))
            {
                if(vg$value[z]==x)
                {
                    for (k in 1:nrow(vg2))
                    {
                        if(vg2$id[k] == vg$id[z])
                        {

                             vg2$value[k]<-m
                             bool<-1
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
        if ( bool == 1)
        {
            m<-m+1
        }
    }}
```